# Android - CouchBase lite - DAO objects - POJO or not

Tags: android, pojo, couchbase-lite

I'm working on an Android app using CouchDB as the db. Data is saved in Json format. I have a city list (name, postal code...), I need to do the `searching` by `name` or `postal code`. I'm using a list view to display and I have a field to do the filter thing. Since the data is in Json format, I have to do the conversion everytime. Would it worths to wrap/convert documents into a POJO list?
I have around 5 db (~10 types of document): 4 pull only and 1 push + pull.
I really need your opinions. Thanks.

Twos schemas:

```
database -> documents -> Json list
```

or

```
database -> documents -> Json -> POJO list
```

Comment: I used Couchdb for a multiple game types application I did. I convert only when the game is running because there will be a lot of computing and get/set stuff... But when listing I use directly the document

Comment: Please repost your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Couchdb for a multiple game types application I did. I convert only when the game is running because there will be a lot of computing and get/set stuff... But when listing I use directly the document